# Unable to update table in superview from subview

Tags: xcode4, subviews, uitableview

I am using Xcode 4.3 and am somewhat of a nubbie in Xcode although I have been a programmer for many years.

I have a UIView called First that contains a UITable that gets its contents from files in memory.  I then create a subview UIView called Second that makes changes in the data files that should change the contents of the table in First.  When I remove Second and return to First, not surprising, the table is not updated. The next time First is loaded from the start, the table reflects the changes that were made.

First contains the method viewDidLoad which is used to load an NSArray from data in files with the data needed by the table. I am able to call viewDidLoad from Second but unless the table is updated from the newly changed NSArray the table will appear as it did before the changes were made.

So my problem is how to call a table method from Second so that the table in First is updated when I remove Second and return to First.  I have tried calling the table method that loads the data into the table but have been unsuccessful since I get compile errors.  I need to know how to call the table function in a way that will result in the table being updated when I return to first.

At least part of my problem is I don't know how the table update is called since it is not called from viewDidLoad as I might have expected.

Sorry, it is a long winded description of the problem.  Much of the rest of the program that I am writing is working and I have been dealing with this issue for several months.  I return every few weeks and take another stab at it but no luck so far.  I really would appreciate any help you can give that will improve my understanding and fix the problem.

Here is the code after the fix:  first (superview) pertinent code

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {  
    NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];  
    NSError* err = nil;  
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.dir'"];  
    NSArray *array = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: userFolder error:&err];  
    self.listData = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];  
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //This does the updating must make table an IBOutlet as  
    [super viewDidLoad];         //described in one of the comments by m. Othman  
}
```

Here is the code after the fix: second (subview) pertinent code. This code located
in the method where changes are made that should effect the table display

```
UIView * start = [self.view superview]; //this line and next two call viewDidLoad in first  
UIResponder * nextResponder = [start nextResponder];  
[nextResponder viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [UIViewController API reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW46)? There are more options beyond -viewDidLoad for dealing with the (re)appearance of a view...

Comment: Joshua - I have tried viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad, and loadView.  Do you have other suggestions?  It seems to me that rather than calling a different method I need to include a method to redraw the table.  What do you think?  Waldo

Comment: Your wording makes me worry you're trying to call these methods directly, rather than *implementing* them in your view controller class for the system to call at the appropriate times.

Comment: I have tried both calling a function from the subview and just removing the subview and letting the function in the superview handle it.  However I have not done it both ways with all the different functions.  I will give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Joshua - If I understood what you suggested - the code in the superview which just updates the NSArray had the name "viewDidLoad".  I changed that name to the other three built in methods: viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and loadView.  None of these other three worked even correctly for even showing the table initially.  If I did not understand what you suggested, please explain.   My problem is that I don't understand how the table is updated since that method is not called from the body of the viewDidLoad method. Again thanks for any suggestions.  I will continue asking hope okay with you.

Comment: here is the pertinent code in first- (notice on the next to last line the code that reloads the table data)                   (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.dir'"];
    NSArray *array = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: userFolder error:&err];
    fm = nil;
    self.listData = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
Here is the pertinent code from second which is the subview

Comment: Joshua,  I am running out of characters when I try to post the code.  I can send to your e-mail or maybe there is a way around the limit.

Answer (score 0):

well, `UITableView` Delegates called just on the loading of the view or when you ask it to reload ..
so in your viewDidLoad or any method that should changes the content of the tableview , you need to write this line

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

I hope I understand your question!!

Comment: M. Othman, This is exactly what I wanted and it makes sense to me.  However when I enter that line of code it says it doesn't know the identifier tableview.  My tableview is spelled tableView but that makes no difference.  So apparently I need to declare tableView in the .h file but there is quite a lengthy parameter list after it and it is not clear what should be included in the declaration.  Sorry, this should be something I know how to do, but don't.  Hope you can help me.

Comment: you just need to declare an outlet for the tableview like
IBOutlet UITableView *tableview ;
and link it  to the table view in the interface builder ...

Comment: M. Othman - super, it worked.  BTW this is the first question I have asked on line.  In the past when I had a question I just doggedly hung in there by trying things and googling what I was having trouble with. If you were nearby I would by you a drink or whatever (I am in Greeley, CO - look me up if you are ever in the neighborhood).   Waldo

Comment: am glad that it worked with you, its not a shame to ask ,I had this issue before and others did and will... and thnx for ur offer and sure i will :)